# A Proposed Change is broken

Tags: bug, status-norepro, documentation, documentation-proposals

[This proposed change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/47596) is very broken:

[image: screenshot]

I can’t even approve or reject.

In chat, [Quill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3296811) pointed out:

> Reading the HTML it seems that first level `ul` inside examples blocks break the top layer `ul` of examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm marking this as [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro), but I see there is still a weird display problem with that change right around here:

[image: Broken out of the box.]

It looks like the issue is with some HTML in the proposed change:

```
### Changing the item marker</h2>

To change the marker, specify the type attribute.
Accepted types are
<ol style="list-style-type:none">
    <li>" 1 " : Number(default)</li> 
    <li>" A " : Uppercase letters</li> 
    <li>" a " : Lowercase letters</li> 
    <li>" I " : Uppercase Roman numbers</li> 
    <li>" i " : Lowercase Roman numbers</li> 
</ol> 
<br /> 
<ol type="a"> 
    <li>Item</li> 
    <li>Some Other Item</li> 
    <li>Another Item</li> 
</ol> 

<h2>Manually changing the numbers ###
```

For some reason, the author mixed header tags with Markdown header notation. Unfortunately, they picked `<h2>` which doesn't match `###`.

Not sure what (if anything) we ought to do there, but the change was not accepted into the [topic copy](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/html/393/lists/1307/ordered-list#t=201609131753307994979).

Comment: @JF:  Is it causing problems somewhere else? I don't see it listed on [the html dashboard](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/html).

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem...